# Reading json string in java

Tags: java, json

I have the following json formatted string:

```
String s = "{ \"_id\" : \"foo.com\", \"categories\" : [], \"ho\" : { \"bnMzMC5==\" : { \"first\" : 1281916800, \"last\" : 1316995200 }, \"bnMyOS5kb21==\" : { \"first\" : 1281916800, \"last\" : 1316995200 } }, \"name\" : [ \"ns.foo.com\", \"ns.bar.com\" ], \"reputation\" : null }"; 


        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(s);
        String output = "";
        for (Object rkey : json.keySet()) {
            Object val = json.get(rkey);
            output += rkey.toString() + "\t" + val.toString() +"\t";
            System.out.println(rkey + " "+ val.toString());

        }
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.random_scripts.JsonRead.main(JsonRead.java:25)
```

What am i missing

Comment: Use eval in JavaScript before send to java to avoid / in string.

Comment: Where's the exception occurring? What's the full trace?

Comment: Wherever `JsonRead.java:25` is, is where your error is. Also, if you're going to be parsing Json in Java, Gson is the way to go.

Comment: @JustinJasmann: This is JsonRead.Java Figured out the error.. I have a field with name "null" and I guess I am trying to convert that toString()..??

Comment: @Fraz Sure, if a value is `null`, calling methods on it will throw an `NPE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your last `json` field: `\"reputation\" : null`

`((Object) json.get("reputation" )).toString();` will result in `NullPointerException` for trying to call `toString()` with a `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

Given string Given string and asked to read specific values like : "Id", "Description", "Key", "Op", "Value", "OT" the here is the way "Exs": [ { "SC": { "Op": "0", "Cri": [{"Id": "12345","Description": "BasedonAPI", "Key": "PM_Id", "Op": "Equals", "Value": ["87"],"OT": ["A", "E","H","P" ],            "EPSO": "False", "RO": null, "RC": null}]}}]
and asked to read specific values like : "Id", "Description", "Key", "Op", "Value", "OT" the here is the way -
Method
public void verifyExpectedValuesInJsonBody( List expectedValues)
throws Exception {

```
    List<String> ExsaddValue = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String> ExskeyValueonapi = new LinkedList<String>();
    ExskeyValueonapi.add("Id");
    ExskeyValueonapi.add("Description");
    ExskeyValueonapi.add("Key");
    ExskeyValueonapi.add("Op");
    ExskeyValueonapi.add("Value");
    ExskeyValueonapi.add("OT");
    
    
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(JsonString); // text is converted to JSON formate.
    logMessage("Json Format VALUE of a Cycle is:: " + json); // Prints the json format of a cycle API.
    
    JSONArray exsvalues = (JSONArray) json.get("Exs"); //Get Exs Array Values from file
    
    logMessage("Exs array values is " + exsvalues .toString()); //Print exs arrya 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < exsvalues .size(); ++i) {
        
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) exsvalues .get(i);    //From Exs Array Read Object 
        JSONObject slvobj = (JSONObject) obj.get("Slv");
        JSONArray cr = (JSONArray) slvobj.get("Cri");
        JSONObject crobj=(JSONObject) cr.get(0);
        
        for (String it : ExskeyValueonapi) {                
            if (it.contentEquals("Value") || it.contentEquals("OT")) {
                JSONArray array = (JSONArray) crobj.get(it);
                logMessage("Value/OT Array Values capture in cri are: "+array);
                for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); ++j) {

                    ExsaddValue.add(array.get(j).toString());
                }           
            }
            else{
            ExsaddValue.add(crobj.get(it).toString());
            }                
        }
    }
    Assert.assertNotNull(ExsaddValue, "Expected list of cri values for Exs is not null");
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedValues.equals(ExsaddValue), ExsaddValue.equals(expectedValues),
            "ERROR:: Expect Exs Values " + expectedValues + "dosen't match with actual values "+ ExsaddValue);
    
    logMessage("PASS:: Expect Exs Values " + expectedValues + "match with actual values  "+ ExsaddValue);

}
```

}

Comment: Given string and asked to read specific values like : "Id", "Description", "Key", "Op", "Value", "OT" the here is the way